# How to return the top 6 rows from a MySql databse

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking for a sql statement that will return the latest 6 items added to the table, based on their id. So if the table has rows with ID's starting at 1 and going until 10, I need a statement that will return the 6 rows with ID's from 5 to 10.

From what I have seen on the web it would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDERBY ID LIMIT 6
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `order by`.  There is a space in the keyword.

Comment: for latest rows if id is set to auto_increment then you need desc in order by `ORDER BY DESC ID LIMIT 6`

Comment: So SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 6 would work ?

Comment: `order by id desc limit 6` would work.  The `desc` goes after each column/expression mentioned in the `order by`.

Comment: Why not get your hands on a MySQL enabled computer?

Comment: Side note - ordering by ids is rarely relevant or useful.  There's _going_ to be gaps, and you're not actually guaranteed that ids are inserted sequentially; this becomes especially true in instances where rows may be updated, and the given ordering should be changed.  If you're looking for "most recent row", you need some sort of `insertedAt` timestamp of similar - the only thing an id should be relied upon for is _uniqueness_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a space in between the `ORDER` and `BY`

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY ID LIMIT 6
```

is the right query

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results in ascending order then you should use

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 6
) t
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

**Explanation:**
The Subselect get the last 6 rows, the outer select sort the result ascending by id.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2a01/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below if your ID is auto incrament

```
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0):

use the limit keyword options: `LIMIT _start,_offset`

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5,6
```

this will return from id 5 to id 10 (or something like)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct... you are just missing the ordering part. Right now, the default is ASC, so you will get IDs 1..6...
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between order and by

SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY ID LIMIT 6